# A Strategy for Sustenance

Tags: riddle, wordplay, music

The following puzzle reveals a song that is probably familiar to a great number of people - though admittedly not everyone.  Can you determine it?

> All of us happen to be tyred,
>   We don't really care whether you like it or not.
>   We're taking a gander at this place we call home,
>   deciding if we're going to put down roots or not.
>
> There's some aquatic creature over there
>   I bet we could be really quiet and asphyxiate it before anyone noticed.
>   Then we could split the spoils, between us.
>
> There's another noise, seemingly from something dwarvish
>   I bet if we looked, nearby, we could find it's vehicle,
>   where it's food is kept, and split that, too.

Comment: I bet in the next verse they put a kitten into a microwave oven. ;)

Comment: @Raystafarian It was - I didn't notice it - Corrected.

Comment: ah, I thought it was "word play" :)

Comment: Must now think of a puzzle in which I can place the word `aspixiate`  LoL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to me like

> ***[The Siamese Cat Song](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/The_Siamese_Cat_Song)***, from the movie *The Lady and the Tramp* (apologies for the gross stereotypical voice of the lyrics, in advance)

All of us happen to be tyred, 
We don't really care whether you like it or not.

> *We are Siamese* if you please.
>
>  We are Siamese if you don't please.*

We're taking a gander at this place we call home,
deciding if we're going to put down roots or not.

> *Now we lookin' over our new domicile.
>
>  If we like we stay for maybe quite a while.*

There's some aquatic creature over there
I bet we could be really quiet and asphyxiate it before anyone noticed.
Then we could split the spoils, between us.

> *Do you seeing that thing swimming round and round?
>
>  Yes. Maybe we can reaching in and make it drown.
>
>  If we sneaking up upon it carefully
>
>  There will be a head for you, a tail for me.*

There's another noise, seemingly from something dwarvish

> *Do you hear what I hear?
>
>  A baby cry?*

I bet if we looked, nearby, we could find it's vehicle,
where it's food is kept, and split that, too.

> *Where we finding baby there be milk nearby.
>
>  If we look in baby buggy there could be
>
>  Plenty milk for you and also some for me.*

Additional connection:

> * The [Siamese cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_cat) is that they have a mutation in their tyrosinase enzyme (TYR) that causes albinism (hence *"tyred"* —thank you, Khale_Kitha)